# detect incompatibility issues in html, css and javascript for modern browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, incompatibility

This may have an existing post with a different title, but I'm not quite sure what to search for,

I wish to scour a large set of html, css and javascript documents for incompatible attributes, tags and functions/variables with modern browsers but am not sure where to start.

so far I've come up with these regular expressions to help identify possible problems:

```
<applet>|<basefont>|<center>|<dir>|<font>|<isindex>|<menu>|<s>|<strike>|<u> ## Deprecated HTML Tags

[ ]align[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]alink[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]background[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]bgcolor[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]clear[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]compact[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]color[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]border[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]hspace[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]link[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]noshade[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]nowrap[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]size[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]start[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]text[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]type[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]value[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]vlink[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]width[ ]*[\=\:]|[ ]vspace[ ]*[\=\:] ## deprecated css attributes (in certain tags).
```

My main aim is to generify our company's website to be compatible with most modern browsers. right now our site malfunctions within anything above IE9 and don't even try to put it on chrome or firefox!

Are there any tools out there to help analyze what may be causing the issues? any help would be great. Even a list of things that are known to cause compatability problems.

Kind regards,
me.

Comment: I'd use https://validator.nu/. Making sure your pages are valid HTML5 will probably go a long way to solving your problem.

Comment: This looks interesting @danielnixon, however it is web based. Is there an offline equivelant? there are lots of files. also there are some jsp's that would mean a bit of interpolation to consider (which would be my problem and I'm not asking anyone for a jsp scanner!).

Comment: You can run it locally: https://validator.github.io/validator/#build-instructions

Comment: hey awesome! thanks for the info, have some internet points.